# Firebase UI cannot show up in a button while building a simple web app

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm just following a tutorial on Google Developers Pathways in [Build your first web app with firebase](https://firebase.google.com/learn/pathways/firebase-web?hl=en) and I'm at the [Step 6](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-web?continue=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Flearn%2Fpathways%2Ffirebase-web%3Fhl%3Den%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fcodelabs%2Ffirebase-get-to-know-web#5). And whenever I test the signing up by clicking the RSVP button, the button would not respond, like the firebase UI sign-up can't show up on the browser's dialog box. I certainly follow all the steps and codes all over.

I try to use the inspect element in the button and something a kind of error shows like this

```
preview-f4664a6cfd526d580909b.js:1 [2021-09-04T13:11:04.250Z]  @firebase/auth: Auth (9.0.0): INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition
console.<computed> @ preview-f4664a6cfd526d580909b.js:1
assert.ts:243 Uncaught (in promise) Error: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition
    at debugFail (assert.ts:243)
    at debugAssert (instantiator.ts:1)
    at _getInstance (instantiator.ts:48)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _initializeAuthInstance (location.ts:1)
    at eval (register.ts:77)
    at Component.eval [as instanceFactory] (register.ts:79)
    at Provider.getOrInitializeService (provider.ts:351)
    at Provider.initialize (provider.ts:257)
    at new Auth (auth.ts:108)
```

Here is my HTML Code

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Firebase Meetup</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/4.0.0/firebaseui.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700|Roboto:300,400,700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">

    <!-- <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-images-a61c9.appspot.com/o/firestore.png?alt=media&token=56d039dc-4a6c-477b-a153-a4bb8234646f" /> -->
    <!-- <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-images-a61c9.appspot.com/o/hosting.png?alt=media&token=57c8adb6-08c4-43f7-9395-4c299896a36c" /> -->
    <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-images-a61c9.appspot.com/o/codelab.png?alt=media&token=f45f808c-ce40-4b34-944c-8d8fac00e13d" />

    <section id="event-details-container">
      <h1>Firebase Meetup</h1>

      <p><i class="material-icons">calendar_today</i> October 30</p>
      <p><i class="material-icons">location_city</i> San Francisco</p>

      <!-- ADDED RVSP BUTTON -->
      <button id="startRsvp">RSVP</button>

    </section>

    <hr>

    <section id="firebaseui-auth-container"></section>

    <section id="description-container">
      <h2>What we'll be doing</h2>
      <p>Join us for a day full of Firebase Workshops and Pizza!</p>
    </section>

    <section id="guestbook-container">
    </section>

  </div>
</body>

<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-app.js";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDj4RNohGUdcRR1slvgZdUVNbKJ2odJkNc",
  authDomain: "fir-web-codelab-398dd.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "fir-web-codelab-398dd",
  storageBucket: "fir-web-codelab-398dd.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "390940575886",
  appId: "1:390940575886:web:5fc4e675e08423b59a21df"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
```

Here is my Javascript Code

```js
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

// Add the Firebase products and methods that you want to use
import { getAuth, EmailAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
import {} from 'firebase/firestore';

import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui';

// Document elements
const startRsvpButton = document.getElementById('startRsvp');
const guestbookContainer = document.getElementById('guestbook-container');

const form = document.getElementById('leave-message');
const input = document.getElementById('message');
const guestbook = document.getElementById('guestbook');
const numberAttending = document.getElementById('number-attending');
const rsvpYes = document.getElementById('rsvp-yes');
const rsvpNo = document.getElementById('rsvp-no');

let rsvpListener = null;
let guestbookListener = null;

let db, auth;

async function main() {
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyDj4RNohGUdcRR1slvgZdUVNbKJ2odJkNc',
    authDomain: 'fir-web-codelab-398dd.firebaseapp.com',
    projectId: 'fir-web-codelab-398dd',
    storageBucket: 'fir-web-codelab-398dd.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '390940575886',
    appId: '1:390940575886:web:5fc4e675e08423b59a21df'
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  auth = getAuth();

  // const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  // FirebaseUI config
  const uiConfig = {
    credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE,
    signInOptions: [
      // Email / Password Provider.
      EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
        // Handle sign-in.
        // Return false to avoid redirect.
        return false;
      }
    }
  };

  const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(auth);

  // Listen to RVSP button clicks
  startRsvpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
  });
}
main();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own problem when I notice that the firebase UI won't appear even if I follow the steps I tried also to run the sample code provided by firebase and at that time it works. But suddenly when I try to refresh the app and click the RVSP button again, the firebase UI won't show up anymore. I go back and read the instructions and it said that "You don't want the page to refresh, because you're building a single-page web app." And that's the reminder, that we should understand at first.